# How to create dummy webcam?

Tags: chrome, camera, v4l, v4l2loopback

I would like to join some videoconference, but I don't own a webcam and the conference software requires one.

So my question is, can I create a dummy one? I don't care what the cam will cast, I just need to appear to have one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is loopback device for that:

https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback

Just add device with modprobe and stream to it with ffmpeg or gstreamer whatever video you want, or anything else for that matter:
https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback/wiki